# <title>word/word | etc..</title> or <title>word-word | etc.</title> re: SEO

Tags: seo, title

With regards to SEO and the title tag would there be a difference between using a / for related words or using a - ?

For example:

```
    Air/Gas Filter | Another Filter | Last Filter
```

or

```
    Air-Gas Filter | Another Filter | Last Filter
```

I've never been sure if it makes a difference. Thanks in advance for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal should be to put keywords in your title tag as though a human were naturally searching for those terms. I can't really imagine anyone typing a hyphen into a search engine in that situation, unless the product specifically has a hyphen in its name. Out of the two options you gave, the slash seems better; a cursory Google search shows that. It's best here to go with what the product is naturally called, since that's what people will be searching for. So, if the product is called an "Air/gas filter," use that in your title tag. If you are selling air and gas filters, then I'd go with, "Air and gas filters."

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about appearing in search engines, I think both would give you the same result.

That being said, the amount of clicks you get, may be something different.

Slashes **(/)** in title tags simply don't look good. That may be something to consider. Dashes **(-)** work fine and are considered by search engines a word separator (for folders and files for example - **abc.com/air-filter-brand/**).

If you have enough space, I would consider using **and** or **& (&)**.

Comment: Dashes are more commonly considered to be a word separator in the URL. The example you gave looks like a good URL, but not such a good title tag.

Comment: @Kenzo I agree, but that was his question. Like I implied, dashes would be better, but if possible, just simply go with & or and.